# If $(x-a)^2=(x+a)^2$ for all values of $x$, then what is the value of $a$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If $(x-a)^2=(x+a)^2$ for all values of $x$, then what is the value of $a$?

At the end when you get $4ax=0$, can I divide by $4x$ to cancel out $4$ and $x$?

Comment: Similar question asked about an hour back

Comment: Choose $x=1$ (or $17$, or any specific number other than $0$), and you can cancel, that is, divide both sides by $4x$.

Comment: Can you write that out please. Thank you.

Comment: This equality holds all $x$.  It obviously holds for $x=0$  So now, as @AndréNicolas suggested, take any $x\ne 0$ and divide both sides of your resulting equality by $x$.  You should find that $a=0$.

Comment: I'm up a lot later than normal so I'll look at this again in the morning, but shouldn't a=0 no matter what you try to do with x?

Comment: If we set $x=0$, we cannot divide both sides by $4x$. (Actually, we need not really worry, we can do a formal division, but that's a more abstract approach).

Comment: Questions change fast nowadays.

Answer (score 8):

Since we know that $$(x-a)^2 = (x+a)^2$$ holds for all $x$,
we particularly know that it holds for $x=a$ as well. Plugging that in the relation yields $$0=4a^2$$ from which we conclude that $a=0$.

Comment: No it doesn't. But it should be frustrating, shouldn't it?

Comment: @mathreadler Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: Yes, $x=a$ is not true unless also $a=0$, so why do you make the assumption $x=a$?

Comment: @mathreadler : That is basic logic: We know that: For all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the proposition $P(x)$ holds. As $a$ is a specific, fixed real number, we also have $P(a)$.
Well, I set $x=a$ to get to the solution in a quick way. I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: But we don't know the $a$ solution will need to be the same, and in fact it doesn't. Since when $x=0$, $a$ can be anything.

Comment: It does not matter what $a$ is. It is a priori a fixed real number. The equation must hold for any number, e.g $x=1$, $x=e$, $x=\pi$, $x=9$, $x=-93$. In particular, the equation must also hold for $x=a$. I use it because then the left hand side cancels. It is just a trick to get to the solution very quick.

Comment: There might exist another $x$ for which $a=0$ does not solve the equation. You would not find those $a$ which are disqualified by other $x$:s if you only plug a particular $x$ and find all $a$ which work for that particular $x$.

Comment: Note that for $a=0$ the equation turns into $x^2=x^2$ which is fulfilled for any $x$. Also, there cannot be any more a's as it is a necessary requirement that the equation holds also for $x=a$. All in all, we proved that if a solution exists, it has to be $a=0$ and that indeed $a=0$ works.

Answer (score 5):

$$(x-a)^2 = (x+a)^2$$
$$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$$
$$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$$
$$-2ax = 2ax$$
$$-a = a$$
Note that this statement is only true when $a=0$, which is thus your solution.

Comment: Why the $b$? I guess it should be $x$...

Comment: @mickep Yep. I rushed through that without thinking... That's what I get for helping out on Math.SE during the middle of the night when I should be sleeping. I fixed it... nice catch.

Comment: You can't divide by $x$ if $x = 0$... A more proper solution is to rewrite to $4ax = 0$ and conclude that either a or x must be 0. If $x = 0$ any $a$ would do and if $a = 0$ any $x$ will do.

Comment: @mathreadler This way works for all $x \neq 0$. The case $x=0$ results in $a=a$, and is thus always true. Thus, accepting $a=0$ from the solution I give allows for $x=0$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying, after expansion of squares you get

$$ a \cdot x = 0 $$

either or both of them can be zero.

However you are specifically given that *for all values of $x$*... So *do  not put* a particular $ x=0. $

Only choice is $ a=0. $

Also for any function if $ f(x+a) = f(x-a)$, then $ a =0.$

Like if $\, e^ { x+a  } \sin ( x+a) = e^ { x-a  } \sin ( x-a) $, then also, $ a=0$

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x-a)^2=(x+a)^2$ for all $x$, then graphs of functions $x\mapsto (x-a)^2$ and $x\mapsto (x+a)^2$ coincide but these are just parabolas with roots at $a$ and $-a$, respectively. Since they must coincide, $a = -a$ which implies $a = 0$.

Comment: if $x = 0$, $a$ could be anything so something is wrong.

Comment: @mathreadler, that's why it says "for all $x$" which basically translates to equality of functions $x\mapsto (x-a)^2$ and $x\mapsto (x+a)^2$. Thus, if $x=0$ doesn't work, try another $x$ :)

Comment: Yep it says so now, anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{(x-a)^2}{(x+a)^2}=1$$
$$\left(\frac{x-a}{x+a}\right)^2=1$$

$$\left(1-\frac{2a}{x+a}\right)^2=1$$
it is clear that $\frac{2a}{x+a}$ should be equal to zero

so, the $$a=0$$

Comment: You are only allowed to divide by $(x+a)^2$ if it is not $0$.

Comment: Also the value inside the square can be $-1$.

Comment: @mathreadler yes you are right ,this case is happened when $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers fit best to solve what you were thinking, but I will write this in the case you want to know more.

If we are working in a polynomial ring like $\mathbb Z _2 \left[ x \right]$, then this equality is always true, as we get that $\left(x-a \right)^2 = \left(x+a \right)^2$ for all $a\in \mathbb Z _2$. This is because in $\mathbb Z _2 = \left\{ 0,1 \right\}$ we have that any element is its own additive opposite (that is to say, $0+0=0$ and $1+1=0$), so $a=-a$ in any of the two cases.

This doesn't happen when working on $\mathbb R$, for example, but I thought it was an interesting thing to add.

Comment: This is true for any field of characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-a)^2 = (x+a)^2$$
Expand squares:
$$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 = x^2 + 2ax + a^2$$
Subtract $x^2+a^2$ from both sides:
$$-2ax = 2ax$$
add $2ax$ and divide by $4$:
$$0 = ax$$

So either 1) $a = 0$ or 2) $x = 0$.

1. $$(x-0)^2 = (x+0)^2 \Leftrightarrow x^2 = x^2$$
   Which is true for all x.
2. $$(0-a)^2 = (0+a)^2 \Leftrightarrow (-a)^2 = (a)^2$$
   Which is true for all $a$.

So either $a=0$ and $x$ can be anything or $x=0$ and $a$ can be anything.